# rails Subscribe To Comments plugin like wordpress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Is there any rails plugin for Subscribe to comments one like the Wordpress has??

i.e. On the comment form, a checkbox to check whether the commenter would opt-in whether to get email notification when a new comment is added?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for DisQus service, you can check [here](http://ukoki.com/post/32631171101/quickly-getting-disqus-up-and-running-on-rails-3-2)  a simple tutorial how to intergrate with Rails 3.2. If you do not want to integrate a third-party service like Disqus, you have [Juvia](http://ukoki.com/post/32631171101/quickly-getting-disqus-up-and-running-on-rails-3-2) [The Comments](https://github.com/phusion/juvia) and [Commontator](https://github.com/lml/commontator), both are mantained and support rails 3 and 4.